# How to change value of multiple fields onchange

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to change the value of **Ordered Qty** (`product_uom_qty`) and **prix unitaire** (`price_unit`) when changing the **Ligne Contrat**. But my `onchange` functions only work for the **Ordered Qty**, although both functions are called correctly.
[image]

Here is my code :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from odoo import api, fields, models, _

# Contrat model
class Contrat(models.Model):
    _name = 'contrat.contrat'
    _rec_name = 'contrat_name'
    contrat_name = fields.Char(string='Nom')
    contrat_number = fields.Integer(string="Numero")
    date_start = fields.Date(string='Date Debut')
    date_end = fields.Date(string="Date Fin")
    date_deadline = fields.Date(string="date echeance")
    ligne_id = fields.One2many('contrat.lignes','ligne_ids',"mylignes")
    # notebook_ids = fields.Many2one('contrat.lignes','ligne_id',string='Notebook')
    client_name = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string="Client")
    bons_ligne_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'contrat_name_id', String='Contrat bons')


class ContratOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'contrat.lignes'
    _rec_name = 'ligne_name'
    ligne_ids = fields.Many2one('contrat.contrat',string="Contrat")
    ligne_name = fields.Char(string="Nom de Ligne")
    unit_price = fields.Float(string='Prix Unitaire')
    article_name = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Article")
    quantity = fields.Float(string='Quantite')

# modifier les lignes des bons de commands
class bons_lignes(models.Model):
    _inherit="sale.order.line"
    bons_po = fields.Integer('PO')
    contrat_name_id = fields.Many2one('contrat.contrat', string='Contrat')
    contrat_lignes_id = fields.Many2one('contrat.lignes', string='Ligne contrat')
    product_uom_qty = fields.Float('qtt', related='contrat_lignes_id.quantity')
    price_unit = fields.Float(string='Prix Unitaire')

    @api.onchange('contrat_lignes_id')
    def onchange_conrat_lignes_id(self):
        self.price_unit = self.contrat_lignes_id.unit_price
```

How is it possible to change both fields with one or more onchange functions.

EDIT: Odoo already has a onchange trigger on field `product_uom_qty` which is changing the field `price_unit` after calling my onchange methods. How is it possible to get my onchange functions get called later, or just forbid Odoo to call its other functions?

Comment: please delete the images with code and add inline code. If you don't know how, read the f****** manual ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner he is a new member he will learn about this in time

Comment: I know, the RTFM was just a well known little hint for him ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner I add the inline code , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single onchange method to change both fields.

```py
@api.onchange('contrat_lignes_id')
def onchange_conrat_lignes_id(self):
    self.product_uom_qty = self.contrat_lignes_id.quantity
    self.price_unit = self.contrat_lignes_id.unit_price
```

Comment: It takes by default the unit price from the products not from my custom module

Comment: @mahmoud You should be more clear about what you want mahmoud the man answered your question if there is an error in computing you can post another question with more detail about it.

Comment: @Cherif oke bro i will

Comment: @Cherif but he is right, the solution won't work, because a quantity change will trigger an onchange method which will again change the price. So this is not the correct solution.

Comment: @CZoellner if you understood what he want you can edit he's question for us. I dind't understand what he want at all

Comment: @CZoellner, you're right . I didn't consider that product_uom_qty already has an onchange method. A quick and dirty solution to this would be to create an empty method called product_uom_change to override the onchange. I wouldn't normally advise doing that but I won't be able to test another method until later tonight.

Comment: @djames take your time :-)